# Not able to make filtered query work with geo_distance. Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's my problem. I have some data stored in an index with the field `"location"`.
Here's the mapping

```
{
    "data":{
        "properties":{
        ...
        "location":{
            "type": "geo_point",
            "lat_lon": true,
            "store": "yes"
        },
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here's is an example of the data present in the index

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "total": 2887,
    "maxScore": 4.8634477
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "_index": "data",
      "_type": "data",
      "_id": "8-HtWNILQrqrobwchhgNIQ",
      "_score": 4.8634477,
      "_source": {
        "generique": "Chemin",
        "_datasetId": "5175b2b4a652945a0500000d",
        "liaison": "",
        "specifique": "Sainte-Foy",
        "direction": "",
        "nomTopo": "Chemin Sainte-Foy",
        "ville": "Québec",
        "arrond": "Sainte-Foy-Sillery-Cap-Rouge",
        "location": {
          "lon": -71.322135,
          "lat": 46.768526
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "data",
      "_type": "data",
      "_id": "sSZ3u-uDQIuPDc2qnPir0g",
      "_score": 4.8634477,
      "_source": {
        "generique": "Chemin",
        "_datasetId": "5175b2b4a652945a0500000d",
        "liaison": "",
        "specifique": "Sainte-Foy",
        "direction": "",
        "nomTopo": "Chemin Sainte-Foy",
        "ville": "Québec",
        "arrond": "Sainte-Foy-Sillery-Cap-Rouge",
        "location": {
          "lon": -71.286977,
          "lat": 46.784508
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I want to perform a request with geo_distance it returned irrelevant data.

Here's the request

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "_datasetId:5175b2b4a652945a0500000d"
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "location": {
            "lat": 46.815569,
            "lon": -71.208401
          },
          "distance": "1km"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The data received doesn't contain the right `"_datasetId"` and doesn't contain `"location"` close from the one given in the query.

I hope I'm clear enough
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually got an answer from the mailing list and I wanted to share it.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/elasticsearch/cxZMZX-bWFA